# How do I loop an existing macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word, repeat

I have a table in MS Word that is 2 columns by 1,000 rows. I made a macro that, in order,

1. adds a new row below the current one,
2. merges the two cells in the new row,
3. cuts and pastes the text from an above cell into the new row,
4. moves an image over one column, and
5. adds text to a cell. Once it completes that string of events the cursor is in position to do it all again.

There are no conditions that can screw it up as it runs (i.e. empty cells, etc), I do not need the code to to look for specific things, I just need it to repeat.

What do I need to add to this existing code to have this repeat until the end of the document (specifically 1,000 times).

I have seen code for Excel, but I have not seen code for going through a table in Word.

```
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Cells.Merge
Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Cut
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
Selection.Font.Size = 4
Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Cut
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Font.Size = 3
Selection.TypeText Text:="Unique specimen identifier not a property tag"
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```

All I expect is to be able to run the code once and have it repeat until it hits the end of the document, and if possible to repeat specifically 1,000 times.

I hope this is not too "broad" since I have the code and am asking a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repeat your set of instructions by wrapping it into a `For...Next` loop, which is fairly standard across VBA applications. This code creates a loop and an 'index' variable, and then tells it to step through that index exactly 1000 times.

```
For index As Integer = 1 To 1000
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Cells.Merge
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
    Selection.Font.Size = 4
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Font.Size = 3
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Unique specimen identifier not a property tag"
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Next
```

If you ever need to loop something an indeterminate amount of times, for example when a specific criterion is met, you would use a `Do...While` or `Do...Until` loop, instead.